# Elementary sequence with the same density as primes

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, number-theory, expectation

I am wondering if there is an elementary sequence that has the same density as the prime numbers.

I tried building one by construction by solving when $n = \frac{x}{\ln (x)}$ is an integer, $n \geq 3$. I got the sequence: $e^{-W_{-1}\frac{1}{n}}$ with $W$ being the product logarithm.

Unfortunately, this isn't elementary and it always outputs a transcendental number. Though, it is much easier to compute than the finding the consecutive primes.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "elementary sequence"?

Comment: You may have a look at *practical numbers* : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks, I was aware of that result. But it isn't easy enough to compute. I am trying to find such a sequence so that I can use it in junction with: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611063/analytic-function-to-find-k-almost-primes-from-prime-factorization) to get better bounds for $k$-almost prime distributions. The order will allow for more concrete patterns than for $k$- almost primes. It is a paraconsistent approach.

Comment: If I understand the spirit of your previous post correctly, would you be open to a solution like: take the DCT of $e^{-W_{-1}(1/n)},$ truncate, then call it a day?

Comment: Oh, and round up or down as appropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by "natural density"?

Comment: @TegLouis That's what I would have understood by "natural density" but it doesn't seem to make much sense in your question. The natural density of the set of prime numbers is zero (a much weaker and easier result than the prime number theorem). I don't believe you are asking if there is an elementary sequence with natural density zero. For example, the sequence $1,4,9,16,25,\dots$ of squares has natural density zero. I wonder what your real question is. Maybe you want a set $A\subset\mathbb N$ such that $|A\cap\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}|$ is asymptotic to $\pi(n)?$

Comment: By the prime number theorem and some extra elementary work the $n$th prime is asymptotically $n\log n$.  So let $A=\{[n\log n]+1: n\in \Bbb N\}$ where $[x]$  is the floor function.